# Convert Csv to JSON with nested array

Tags: python, arrays, json, csv, nested

I have a CSV file

```
group, first, last
fans, John, Smith
fans, Alice, White
students, Ben, Smith
students, Joan, Carpenter
...
```

The Output JSON file needs this format:

```
[
{
  "group" : "fans",
  "user" : [
    {
      "first" : "John",
      "last" :  "Smith"
    },
    {
      "first" : "Alice",
      "last" :  "White"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "group" : "students",
  "user" : [
    {
      "first" : "Ben",
      "last" :  "Smith"
    },
    {
      "first" : "Joan",
      "last" :  "Carpenter"
    }
  ]
}
]
```

Comment: Sorry, the csv file with 3 columns, group, first, last

Comment: So, what is your problem?

Comment: How to convert this csv to the json file with nested array

Comment: I mean what is wrong with your code? What language do you use?

Comment: Sorry, I am using python.  The problem for me is how to nest the array. Do I need to create a json file with first and last  and ...?  The strategy is kind of confuse. I can create a json file with three fields: group, first and last, but how to group first and last with group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**
Use `itertools.groupby`, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

**Long answer**
This is a multi-step process.

Start by getting your CSV into a `list` of `dict`:

```
from csv import DictReader
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    r = DictReader(csvfile, skipinitialspace=True)
    data = [dict(d) for d in r]
```

`groupby` needs sorted data, so define a function to get the key, and pass it in like so:

```
def keyfunc(x):
    return x['group']

data = sorted(data, key=keyfunc)
```

Last, call `groupby`, providing your sorted data and your key function:

```
from itertools import groupby
groups = []
for k, g in groupby(data, keyfunc):
    groups.append({
        "group": k,
        "user": [{k:v for k, v in d.items() if k != 'group'} for d in list(g)]
    })
```

This will iterate over your data, and every time the key changes, it drops into the `for` block and executes that code, providing `k` (the key for that group) and `g` (the `dict` objects that belong to it). Here we just store those in a list for later.

In this example, the `user` key uses some pretty dense comprehensions to remove the `group` key from every row of `user`. If you can live with that little bit of extra data, that whole line can be simplified as:

```
"user": list(g)
```

The result looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "group": "fans",
    "user": [
      {
        "first": "John",
        "last": "Smith"
      },
      {
        "first": "Alice",
        "last": "White"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group": "students",
    "user": [
      {
        "first": "Ben",
        "last": "Smith"
      },
      {
        "first": "Joan",
        "last": "Carpenter"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. And I got NameError: name 'groupby' is not defined. Do you have any idea what is wrong with it?

Comment: I missed an import - `from itertools import groupby`. Fixed now.

Comment: If I have another column called group ID, how can I group users by both group and group ID?